# Recovering from hibernate optimistic locking exception

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, optimistic-locking

I have a method like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doSomeWork(){
 Entity = entity = dao.loadEntity();
 // do some related work
 ...
 try {
  dao.saveEntity(entity);
 }
 catch(StaleObjectStateException sose){
  dao.flush(entity);
  doSomeWork();
 }
}
```

I was expecting that by using REQUIRES_NEW transaction propagation and the recursion shown, the StaleObjectStateException would eventually clear but this isn't the case.

How do I recover from this exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out there's a bit of a 'gatcha' which I've overlooked...

From spring docs

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only 'external' method calls
>   coming in through the proxy will be intercepted. This means that
>   'self-invocation', i.e. a method within the target object calling some
>   other method of the target object, won't lead to an actual transaction
>   at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with @Transactional!

Because I've been recursing internally, the transaction demarcation wasn't getting applied.

The solution is to recurse via the proxy, like this...

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void doSomeWork(){
 Entity = entity = dao.loadEntity();
 // do some related work
 ...
 try {
  dao.saveEntity(entity);
 }
 catch(StaleObjectStateException sose){
  dao.flush(entity);
  applicationContext.getBean(this.getClass()).doSomeWork();
 }
}
```