# Retry mechanism for optimistic locking (spring data + JPA)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, optimistic-locking

We decided on using optimistic locking in our web application in order to increase concurrency and without the using of pessimistic locking.

We are now on a lookout for retry solutions.

We would like to have as little impact as possible to our current code base.

One of the solutions we saw on the web is using a retry interceptor with annotation to mark a method as retry able.

Problem is we would like to annotate methods that are having the @Transactional annotation on them but the interceptor fails to retry them for some reason. (the interceptor retries non transactional methods perfectly.)

So:

1) Are there any alternatives for the retry that will have minimum impact on our code?

2) Are there any documentations \ tutorials for that solution?

3) Is it even possible to retry a @Transactional annotated method?

Cheers!

Answer (score 11):

## Ad 3.

You can use [Spring Retry](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-retry) to retry **transacted** method when a version number or timestamp check failed (optimistic lock occurs).

### Configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableRetry
public class RetryConfig {

}
```

### Usage

```
@Retryable(StaleStateException.class)
@Transactional
public void doSomethingWithFoo(Long fooId){
    // read your entity again before changes!
    Foo foo = fooRepository.findOne(fooId);

    foo.setStatus(REJECTED)  // <- sample foo modification

} // commit on method end
```

Use `@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` for retrying only the code from annotated method.

Comment: “SQLException: Statement closed.” occurred when retiring.

Comment: @xiemeilong I had the same error as you with Hibernate 5.0.x. It went away with 5.2.14.Final. It took me almost a day to figure that out. :(

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisBeauchef  thank you very much, I will try it later.

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways to achieve this as follows

**[Recovering from hibernate optimistic locking exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12252535/recovering-from-hibernate-optimistic-locking-exception)**

**OR**

**[Using Spring AOP to Retry Failed Idempotent Concurrent Operations](http://josiahgore.blogspot.in/2011/02/using-spring-aop-to-retry-failed.html)**

hope this will help you..!

Comment: Ashish, we already tried the second solution, apperantly it is not working when you use it on Transactional methods, do you have any idea why?

Comment: I followed exactly what is being written in http://josiahgore.blogspot.in/2011/02/using-spring-aop-to-retry-failed.html    and then i annotated a service method with      @RetryConcurrentOperation(exception = HibernateOptimisticLockingFailureException.class, retries = 12)
   Now, because the method is annotated with @Transactional it doesnt work, it gives a regular optimistic lock exception,  on a non transactional method if i annotate it - it works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason your retry cannot work is that @Transactional priority is higher than @Aspect.

You should make @Aspect higher priority by **implementing Ordered** in TryAgainAspect class

Interceptor class:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class TryAgainAspect implements Ordered {

private int maxRetries;
private int order = 1;

public void setMaxRetries(int maxRetries) {
    this.maxRetries = maxRetries;
}

public int getOrder() {
    return this.order;
}

@Pointcut("@annotation(IsTryAgain)")
public void retryOnOptFailure() {
}

@Around("retryOnOptFailure()")
public Object doConcurrentOperation(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    MethodSignature msig = (MethodSignature) pjp.getSignature();
    Object target = pjp.getTarget();
    Method currentMethod = target.getClass().getMethod(msig.getName(), msig.getParameterTypes());
    IsTryAgain annotation = currentMethod.getAnnotation(IsTryAgain.class);
    this.setMaxRetries(annotation.tryTimes());

    int numAttempts = 0;
    do {
        numAttempts++;
        try {
            return pjp.proceed();
        } catch (ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException | StaleObjectStateException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
            if (numAttempts > maxRetries) {
                throw new NoMoreTryException("System error, all retry failed");
            } else {
                System.out.println("0 === retry ===" + numAttempts + "times");
            }
        }
    } while (numAttempts <= this.maxRetries);

    return null;
}

}
```

IsTryAgain:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface IsTryAgain {
    int tryTimes() default 5;
}
```

Your service class method should add annotation @IsTryAgain and @Transactional

```
@IsTryAgain
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public Product buyProduct(Product product) {
// your business logic 
}
```